# Database Design: Many-to-many question

Tags: database-design

I have a database with these tables:

products,colors,sizes

Each product(t-shirts,jeans etc) can have multiple colors and each color can have multiple sizes

*EDIT*

Products can share colors and colors can share sizes

So I've made an xref_products_colors table and xref_color_sizes table. Is that OK or there is a better way to design this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is self-explanatory.

[image: product_color_size]

Comment: Answer needs to be revised. Attached image is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't each pair of jeans with different colors their own product? A product is "unique" in its collection of sizes and colors.

I would do something like this:

`Collection` or `Brand` might even have both where a `Collection` aggregates a Brand.

Then I would have this layout in `products`

`Id`, `Size`, `Color`, `Collection`

However, you would see mulitple lines of Size, Color in this scenario so you could even see a different Color as a Different `Collection` whereas the `Collection` table could look like this:

`Id`, `Brand`, `Color`

And then you attach the `Products` with a specific size to the `Collection` like this:

`Id`, `Collection`, `Size` having it a bit more normalized.

Comment: its x = the x of the it; it's = it is => its collection.

Comment: *@Konerak:* I beg your pardon?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you need to either adopt Mr Niedermair's suggestion or have three tables, PRODUCT with a product_id key, COLOURS with a product_id and colour_id key, and SIZES with a product_id, colour_id and size_id key.

It isn't really an N-to-N relationship although it looks like it, because someone who wants a red shirt isn't likely to be interested in a red car as an alternative.

Edit - the answer I referred to has just disappeared. In it, the responder suggested having a table PRODUCT keyed on product, colour and size.

Comment: That last bit in the edit; a single table keyed on product_id, colour_id and size_id. Which makes sense provided there are no particular properties associated with red hats as opposed to blue hats.